# Relative path to config file in PHP project

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. I'm developing a new PHP website. My website folder structure is as below,

```
-SystemRoot
    +Code
    +Data_Access
    -Public_HTML
        +css
        +js
        +Templates
    -resources
        config.php
```

There I have a config file in resources directory, I need to include `config.php` in most of other php pages in various directories. So I have to specify the path to config file differently in different pages like,

```
include_once '../resources/config.php';
include_once '../../resources/config.php';
```

Is there a way to overcome this & use a common (relative) path to `config.php` that can be used in eny folder path within the project?

What is the common/best practice to include classes in php projects?

Comment: Is your working directory the Public_HTML folder?  Or SystemRoot?  (where is your index file?)

Comment: @James index.php is in System root & other web pages in Public_HTML

Comment: Then if SystemRoom is your domain.com/ directory, all you have to do when including is use the relative path "/include/path". That way, the included path starts from your SystemRoom. So if your included file is in "SystemRoot/resources/config.php", you should just have to include_once("/resources/config.php"); in any file. (in other words, just start the path with a leading "/")

Comment: @James Starting path with "/" is not working it seems...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it was late and I wasn't thinking straight.  That only works with `<a>` tags within the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could route everything to your index.php

then define some constant's.  Evrything routed to index.php will have access to these then.

```
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

define('RESOURCES', SELF . 'resources/');
```

Answer (score 4):

I've done pretty much what you've done in the past, except that my `require()`s are done differently:

```
require_once(str_replace('//','/',dirname(__FILE__).'/') .'../../config.php');
```

I then define other paths that can be used throughout like so:

```
// DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a PHP pre-defined constant
// (\ for Windows, / for Unix)
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Define Views URL path
defined('VIEW_URL') ? null : define('VIEW_URL', '/application/views');

// Define CSS URL path
defined('CSS_URL') ? null : define('CSS_URL', '/public/css');

// Define JavaScripts URL path
defined('JS_URL') ? null : define('JS_URL', '/public/js');

// Define site root
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 
  define('SITE_ROOT', str_replace('//','/',dirname(__FILE__)));

// Define App path as 'application' directory
defined('APP_PATH') ? null : define('APP_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'application');

// Define Includes path as 'application/includes' directory
defined('INC_PATH') ? null : define('INC_PATH', APP_PATH.DS.'includes');

// Define Helpers path as 'application/helpers' directory
defined('HELP_PATH') ? null : define('HELP_PATH', APP_PATH.DS.'helpers');

// Define Controllers path as 'includes/classes' directory
defined('CTLR_PATH') ? null : define('CTLR_PATH', APP_PATH.DS.'controllers');

// Define Models path as 'includes/classes' directory
defined('MOD_PATH') ? null : define('MOD_PATH', APP_PATH.DS.'models');

// Define Views path as 'includes/classes' directory
defined('VIEW_PATH') ? null : define('VIEW_PATH', APP_PATH.DS.'views');
```

Answer (score 3):

Start your script with `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`. From there all your `include`s and any other file functions such as `file_exists`, `fopen` and so on will work from the root directory of your website (usually `public_html`).

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest if you were not already working in the root directory.

Comment: @kolink <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?> gives 'D:/workspace' which is the parent directory of the SystemRoot Directory. Is something wrong (with my php config)?

Comment: Are you using a windows server?

Answer (score 0):

If using php 5.x check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php